How does the file command determine the file type?
I have a hexdump of a file. Running file indicates that this is a POSIX tar archive (GNU). On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures, I see that the hexdump of a tar archive should contain 75 73 74 61 72 00 30 30 or
75 73 74 61 72 20 20 00 . The file however does not contain those hex signatures. How does file know that this is a tar archive? Also, file seems to think that certain compressed files are ASCII even if they are gzip compressed. Does this mean that file is unreliable?
Hexdump:
00000000: 6461 7461 352e 6269 6e00 0000 0000 0000  data5.bin.......
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 3030 3030 3634 3400 3030 3030  ....0000644.0000
00000070: 3030 3000 3030 3030 3030 3000 3030 3030  000.0000000.0000
00000080: 3030 3234 3030 3000 3134 3634 3537 3634  0024000.14645764
00000090: 3732 3200 3031 3132 3631 0020 3000 0000  722.011261. 0...



your Hexdump is too short, the signature is at postion 257 (i.e. 101 hex) as documented in the wikipedia page

i.e. file looks at appropriate places in the file, verifying file structure and whatnot, not only at the very first bytes. I'd consider file to be fairly reliable.
